# Custom URL aliases in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, url-rewriting, drupal-6

I have several pages in my drupal website that produce custom query strings. The query string values and aliases I want to use are referenced from a MYSQL database.

I've seen examples for this in Drupal 5 using the custom_url_rewrite function but not in 6... can somebody provide me with an example of how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by 'produce custom query strings'. Adding a little example of what you want to achieve might also help ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what it is you want to do, but the function you reference, has been divided into two functions in Drupal 6: [custom_url_rewrite_outbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/custom_url_rewrite_outbound/6) and [custom_url_rewrite_inbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/custom_url_rewrite_inbound/6).

I don't hope you will use the url run queries against your database, that can quickly become a gaping security hole.

Answer (score 0):

The path module is part of core and does what I think you want, with a little coding. You may also find [PathAuto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) will help you.